Closed form for an alternating cosecant sum
Is there any closed form for the following finite sum
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^j}{\sin (\frac{j\pi}{n})}$$
where $n$ is an even number?
Any comment or reference is welcome.

One idea might be to use the Euler reflection formula to write
$$
\frac{(-1)^j}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi j}{n}\right)}
= \frac{(-1)^j \Gamma\left(\frac{j}{n}\right) \Gamma\left(1-\frac{j}{n}\right)}{\pi}.
$$ and look for an expression in terms of a hypergeometric series.

Mathematica cannot do anything with this sum. So, it is unlikely to have a closed-form expression.

This sum is some kind of error term. If we express linear function $f(x)=x$ as a finite Fourier series (FFS) (using values at integer points), then this sum will be the value of FFS at half-integer point.

I noted that
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^j}{\sin\left(\frac{j\pi}n\right)}=-\frac 2n\sum_{j=0}^{(n-2)/2}(2j+1)\cot\left(\frac{(2j+1)\pi}{2n}\right),$$
which is not really a simplification but perhaps has some interest. This follows by differentiating the finite Fourier series
$$\sin(n x)\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^j}{\sin\left(x+\frac{j\pi}n\right)}=-2\sum_{j=0}^{(n-2)/2}\cot\left(\frac{(2j+1)\pi}{2n}\right)\sin((2j+1)x).$$

The sum can be rewritten as an integral, by means of
$$\frac{1}{\sin (\pi j/n)}=\frac{n}{\pi}\int_0^\infty\frac{s^{j-1}}{  s^n+1}\,ds,\;\;0<j<n,$$
$$\Rightarrow \sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^j}{\sin (\pi j/n)}=-\frac{n}{\pi}\int_0^\infty \frac{(-1)^n s^{n-1}+1}{ (s+1)(s^n+1)}\,ds=\begin{cases}
0&\text{for odd}\;\;n,\\
-\frac{2n}{\pi}\int_0^1\frac{s^{n-1}+1}{ (s+1)(s^n+1)}\,ds&\text{for even}\;\;n.
\end{cases}
$$
This does not simplify further for arbitrary even $n$. The large-$n$ asymptotics for even $n=2p$ can be readily derived from the integral expression,
$$\lim_{p\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{2p}\sum_{j=1}^{2p-1}\frac{(-1)^j}{\sin (\pi j/n)}= -\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^1\frac{1}{s+1}\,ds=-\frac{2}{\pi}\ln 2=-0.441271.$$
 Higher order terms in a series expansion were evaluated by Blagouchine in On a generalization of Watson's trigonometric sum, or Dowker's sum of order one half,
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^j}{\sin (\pi j/n)} = -\frac{\,2n\ln2\,}{\,\pi\,}\:
-   2\sum_{r=1}^{N-1} \frac{\,(-1)^{r+1}\big(2^{2r-1}-1\big)
\big(2^{2r}-1\big)\pi^{2r-1} B^2_{2r}\,}{\,r\, (2r)!\, n^{2r-1}\,}  \, +   \, O\big(n^{1-2N}\big),$$
where the $B_p$ are Bernoulli numbers and $n$ is even. The first few terms are
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^j}{\sin (\pi j/n)} =-\frac{\,2n\ln2\,}{\,\pi\,}
-\frac{\pi}{\,12\, n\,} +\frac{7\pi^3}{\,1440\,n^3\,} -\frac{31\pi^5}{\,30\,240\,n^5\,}+\frac{2159\pi^7}{\,4\,838\,400\,n^7\,}+\dotsb.
$$



As a curiosity, I note that the sum for odd $n$, with an offset $\phi$ in the argument of the sine, can be evaluated in closed form: $$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^j}{\sin(\phi+\pi j/n)}=\frac{n}{\sin n\phi},\;\;n=1,3,5,\dotsc.$$
A result due to Euler, see On a finite sum of cosecants appearing in various problems.

Thank you for your answer. I also noted the result of odd $n$. For even $n$, I could not find it anywhere.

I think in the integrand, $(-s)^{n-1}+1$ should be $1-(-s)^{n-1}$

thank you for alerting me to this typo, now corrected.

I'm not sure if this representation is really helpful, but the above sum $S_n$ can be written in terms of the $q$-digamma function $\psi_q(z)$. Define $q=r\exp(2\pi i/n)$ and $m=\lfloor n/4\rfloor$, with $r<1$ and even $n$, then
\begin{align}
S_n &= 1 + \frac{n}{\pi}\lim_{r\to1^-}
\big[
\psi_q\left( 1 \right)
-\psi_q\left(\tfrac{1}{2}\right)
+\psi_q\left(m+\tfrac{n}{2}+1\right)
-\psi_q\left(m+\tfrac{n}{2}+\tfrac{1}{2}\right)
 \\
&
\qquad{}
-\psi_q(m+1)
+\psi_q\left(m+\tfrac{1}{2}\right)
-\psi_q\left(\tfrac{n}{2}+1\right)
+\psi_q\left(\tfrac{n}{2}+\tfrac{1}{2}\right)
\big].
\label{eq:1}\tag{1}
\end{align}
Mathematica finds this representation if one uses the symmetry $ j \leftrightarrow n-j$ and splits the sum into even and odd parts.

I am not familiar with the digamma function. I will look into it.
